# How can I slowdown the ffmpeg encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to use ffmpeg to simulate a video capture source. `ffmpeg -i some.mp4 -c:v rawvideo output.raw.pipe` However, the decoding-encoding is too fast. I want it produce the frame at frame rate of some.mp4 (for example 10 fps). Is there any way to achieve this in ffmpeg?

Comment: why people just keep voting down without any reason?

Comment: Because this is not a programming question and does not belong on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ffmpeg man page. Specifically the -re option.